# Scraping using selenium and xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from here:

http://www.creditcardcompare.com.au/credit-cards.php

In particular I want to get the data associated with this xpath:

```
//*[@id="sortable-offer-list"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]
```

Using selenium and using Chrome as the browser I have tried the following:

```
driver.get('http://www.creditcardcompare.com.au/credit-cards.php')
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
data=tree.xpath('//*[@id="sortable-offer-list"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]')
```

I want it to return "$0 p.a.", but it does not return anything. What do I need to do to fix this up?

(I understand that this is probably a basic thing, but I have not done anything like this before.)

Comment: When you say "$0 p.a." do you mean "0% p.a." or "$0 annual fee"? Also, there are many instances of "0% p.a." on that page; which one do you want?

Comment: @LarsH I want to get the "$0 p.a." associated with this bit of html code:

 `<div class="product1listcontent fn1normal"><h3 class="product1title fn1bold fshead">Rates &amp; Fees</h3><div class="product1titleseparator"></div><div class="tabcrfcontent fscontent fblack"><div class="tabcrfleft"><div class="tabcrftype"><div class="tabcrftext">Additional Card Fee</div><div class="tabcrfcont1">$0 p.a.</div><div class="tabcrevupdots"></div></div>`

That is the "$0 p.a." that is found when choosing 'More info' on the first card, selecting 'Rates and Fees', and corresponding to 'Additional card fee.'

Comment: How about `//div[@class='tabcrftext' and text()='Additional Card Fee']/following-sibling::div[1]/text()`? That should give you *all* the values on the page for Additional Card Fee, of which you can just take the first if that's what you want.

Comment: I gave that a go @LarsH but it still does not return anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you checked that the output from `driver.get('http://www.creditcardcompare.com.au/credit-cards.php')` is the same as the HTML in Chrome? If it's running Javascript after the page loads, they may be different.

Comment: @LarsH Ok, it seems like this is the problem. I have tried switching to firefox and running `profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`
`profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)`
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)`
`driver.get('http://www.creditcardcompare.com.au/credit-cards.php')`
as per some advice I found on another question, but this hasn't worked. Any suggestions for how to overcome the Javascript problem?

Comment: Basically you need to use a tool that operates on the HTML/DOM as it is after the Javascript has run its course. That would be a tool that sits on top of a browser. Which is what Selenium is designed to do. I'm not familiar enough with Selenium to know how to modify what you're doing to get at the post-Javascript page content.